# How to edit "Version: xxx" from a script to automate a debian package build?

Tags: jenkins, sed

The Debian control file has a line like this (among many others):

```
  Version: 1.1.0
```

We are using jenkins to build our application as a .deb package.  in Jenkins we are doing something like this:

```
 cp -r $WORKSPACE/p1.1/ourap/scripts/ourapp_debian $TARGET/
 cd $TARGET
 fakeroot dpkg-deb --build ourapp_debian
```

We would like to do shomething like this in our control file:

```
 Packages: ourapp
 Version: 1.1.$BUILD_NUMBER
```

but obviously this is not possible.

So we need something like a sed script to find the line starting with Version: and replace anything after it with a constant plus the BUILD_NUMBER env var which Jenkins creates.

We have tried things like this:

```
$ sed -i 's/xxx/$BUILD_NUMBER/g' control
```

then put "Version: xxx" in our file, but this doesn't work, and there must be a better way?

Any ideas?

We don't use the change-log, as this package will be installed on servers which no one has access to.  the change logs are word docs given to the customer.
We don't use or need any of the Debian helper tools.

Comment: Why not create the file from scratch instead of replacing something and adding a line above?

Comment: regarding this command alone: `sed -i 's/xxx/$BUILD_NUMBER/g' control` you should quote with double quotes..

Answer (score 1):

Create two files:

**f.awk**

```
function vp(s) { # return 1 for a string with version info
    return s ~ /[ \t]*Version:/
}

function upd() { # an example of version number update function
    v[3] = ENVIRON["BUILD_NUMBER"]
}

vp($0) {
    gsub("[^.0-9]", "") # get rid of everything but `.' and digits
    split($0, v, "[.]") # split version info into array `v' elements

    upd()

    printf "Version: %s.%s.%s\n", v[1], v[2], v[3]
    next # done with this line
}

{ # print the rest without modifications
    print 
}
```

**f.example**

```
rest1
Version: 1.1.0
rest2
```

Run the command

```
BUILD_NUMBER=42 awk -f f.awk f.example
```

Expected output is

```
rest1
Version: 1.1.42
rest2
```

Answer (score 1):

With single quote:

```
sed -ri "s/(Version.*\.)[0-9]*/\1$BUILD_NUMBER/g" <control file>
```

OR

```
sed  -ni  "/Version/{s/[0-9]*$/$BUILD_NUMBER/};p" <control file>
```